# How do you make image height suit the content of the column beside it?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following code

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
}

.ninja {
  font-family: Bebas Neue;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:80%">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="3" width="50%">
      <img style="display: block;width: 100%;height: 100%" src="image.jpg" />
    </th>
    <td valign="top"><strong class=n inja>WHY WONT YOU LET IT GO</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 0;">
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 0;">
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>HAHAHAHA</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is, the text all have big spaces all the way down because their total height has to account for the image's height. How do I make it the other way around as I would be fine with the image being minimized or made smaller so the text does not have the long spaces below their content?

Comment: are you using bootstrap or other css? Just right click onthe image and inspect. that will give you clues.

Comment: You could try embedding the image as a background to a div or other element and set it to fit without repeating.  Then resize the element's width/height to fit inside the cell.